# Can't Access Port 8080 on Public Servers

Tags: networking, internet, ports

I have a slightly weird problem that I can't really understand.

A lot of people host their Tomcat services, such as Geoserver, on port 8080, but when I try to access these from my browser in my current location, I just get a timeout error as if there were no response from the server (network monitor in Chrome shows that DNS resolution happened but no response from server).

Having found this, I emailed the administrator of a service I am trying to access to report that his server was down and he said that the service is working fine and can be accessed normally.

I tried using a VPN to access the service from my office computer in the UK (as I'm out of the country right now) and the connection succeeded.

I know nothing about networking protocols, so is there an explanation for a specific port being unavailable not because inbound traffic is blocked at the server end, but because the router or ISP at my end will not receive traffic from that port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talk to the administrator of your local network. It appears they prohibit outbound TCP connections to port 8080.